# Is there a difference between generating mongoId on application level or leaving it to mongo?

Tags: mongodb

In all my previous applications I was generating ObjectID on the application side and provided it to Mongo for inserts. On the other hand there is nothing wrong with leaving it and allowing   Mongo to generate it by itself. Right now I am wondering: is there any difference.

I know that sometimes you need to use this ObjectID later and if you generate it by yourself you should not worry about it (I am also aware that if you just asking mongo to insert it it does not necessarily guarantee that it will insert it)

Comment: Many drivers do this on the client anyway, so it's really a matter of personal preference.

Comment: If you're talking about the `_id`, yes. (This is true for many of the MongoDB drivers). It's your responsibility for other fields.

Comment: _id is actually designed to be done application side and is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that most drivers will already generate the `ObjectId` for the `_id` field on the application side.

The [`ObjectId` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) states that if you do not specify the `_id` field on the insert command:

> the mongod adds the _id field and generates a unique ObjectId to assign as its value

To answer your question of whether there is any difference, in practical terms I would say **not much**. In terms of `ObjectId` internals, you'll have a different machine ID and process ID depending on where it was generated... but you'd hardly ever be concerned about that.

In terms of application development, if you're generating the `ObjectId` before insertion, you have access to that value before the insert is done. So if you're inserting a referenced document at the same time you could do so a tiny bit easier.

In summary though, I'd say **no**, there's really not much of a difference in letting `mongod` generate your `ObjectId` vs generating it yourself.